# Resolution with windows 10 and a TV in mirror by HDMI

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

I experiment problem with windows 10, when I connect my tv with HDMI, resolution on my computer screen get very big. when I go to set resolution parameter, they are all good ( 1920x1080).
When I unplug HDMI to TV, resolution get OK.

I have a Nvidia card Geforce 210 and I have nvidia drivers 341.81 installed
I tried to move all driver settings, but I couldn't change it....
Before, in windows 7, I didn't have this problem.
I already experimented the same issue with Ubuntu...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to set you pc/laptop screen to the desired/best resolution and say duplicate these screens. The HDTV will display in its own resolution, even if its lower than on your pc.

Comment: My problem is with "Duplicate Screen". When I chosse extends screen, I have no problem, my desktop has good resolution, but when I chose duplicate screen, my desktop says I am in 1920x1080 but it appears to be much smaller